# TeamCity "Cannot resolve symbol" in Code Inspections .NET

Tags: c#, .net, continuous-integration, teamcity, resharper

We are running TeamCity 10.0.1.
The build steps for our project include the step "Inspections (.NET)", which is supposed to run the resharper code inspection.
The build itself and the unit tests are all succeeding but the result of the Inspection shows a lot of errors:

```
4: Cannot resolve symbol 'Drawing'
141: Cannot resolve symbol 'Image'
154: Cannot resolve symbol 'Bitmap'
155: Cannot resolve symbol 'Graphics'
[...]
```

This is obfuscating the real issues we should address.

Does anybody know why the inspections show this kind of error although the build is succeeding and how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with the code inspection at TeamCity 10.0.2 after installing the latest "JetBrains Resharper Command Line Tools" - 2017.2.2.

Using the previous one version

[image]

and assigning it to the build step

[image]

helped.

*It seems that TeamCity 10.x can't work well with the 2017.xxx R# command line inspection tool. Maybe some parameters are not well passed....(?) I guess that upgrading to the TeamCity 2017.xxx and using the R# command line inspetion tool of a version 2017.x would solved the problem too.*

Comment: By the time i asked that question there was no 2017.xxx version yet and since i moved to a newer TeamCity Version by now where this problem no longer occurs i can't check if this would help. But thank you for your time anyway.